# how do I hide byobu status line?

Tags: terminal, tmux, byobu

You know, in tmux there's an option `set -g status off` that allows me to hide the tmux status bar, can I do the same with byobu?

I can't find any option that allows me to hide the status bar and gives me an extra line, any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You absolutely can.

Just add `set -g status off` into the configuration file `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Answer (score 0):

You can also move it to the top, to free lines at the bottom but to keep the functionality itself:

set-option -g status-position top